My mother, Estate Income Tax, a living revocable trust and the 645 Election
In June of 2023 my  mother died. At the time of her death she owned income producing assets such as stocks. Some of the assets were held directly in her name and others were held inside her living revocable trust.
For the year she died, an estate income tax must be filed. After her death, the revocable trust becomes irrevocable. The decision is made to make the 645 election for the trust. Given these facts, can her executor make the income tax return for the estate final and still leave the trust open with plans to file additional tax returns in the next year?

I think you want professional advice on this one, from someone who knows the local laws as well as the national ones.


Given these facts, can her executor make the income tax return for the estate final and still leave the trust open with plans to file additional tax returns in the next year?

Yes, but the election lapses once the estate is closed.
You should probably work with a professional, trust and estate taxation is not trivial, and trust compliance is a legal issue which requires a qualified attorney to guide you. I surely hope you didn't make this election without a proper tax professional guiding you through the details.

You wrote:  the election lapses once the estate is closed.  Are you sure about that? I am thinking that it closes once all the assets are out of the  estate and the trust but I am not sure of my facts.
